# Secondary menu shows for registed users only

Tags: routes, navigation

I have created a theme from scratch but secondary menu show only two items for non logged users but show all of them in logged users. Also this menu has sub items but it won't show at all, whether for logged or not users and the `Show as expanded` options is selected.

here is the code I am using:

```
  <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array('links' => $secondary_menu,'attributes' => array('id' => 'toolMenu'))); ?>
```

How shall I fix that?

Comment: Does this happen when you use built-in theme, too? Test it - it's the simplest way to tell if it is a problem with your code, or with permission settings.

Comment: Have you checked that the logged in users and anonymous user have access permissions to the menu links? If not then Drupal will not show the menu items.